# extract specific rows in a new sheet based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with hundreds of steps(one on each row) and each column represents a scenario. If that step is executed in the scenario there is a value "x" in the same row.

I would like to extract the data from this sheet to another sheet where for each scenario I would see just the steps executed in it. (a scenarios has a few steps).

Here is a representation of what I would like to do

[image: How the data looks like and how I would like it to look]

I tried using advanced filtering function but it did not give me the results i would like and I am not very skilled at writing IF conditions. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this array formula in J3 if your data is as per my screenshot and drag it as required.

> =IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$12,SMALL(IF(ISTEXT(B$3:B$12),ROW($A$1:$A$10)),ROW(A1))),"")

[image]

Comment: I copy pasted the formula in J3. The  J3 "Step 1" is correctly calculated but when i drag to expand the formula all the other rows in column J are blank. First row has the formula as you typed it but the next one (J4) looks like `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$12,SMALL(IF(ISTEXT(B$3:B$12),ROW($A$1:$A$10)),ROW(A2))),"")` , J5 formula ends in`ROW(A3))),"")`.

Comment: @Shiny you need to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter in J3 and then drag it as it's an array formula

Answer (score -1):

You may try to use a pivot table, where rows are the steps and columns are the scenarios. Use scenarios as values and using the count instead sum.

That way you can later on the output sheet use de getpivotdata to fill it.